# Trouble with selecting last non blank row in reference

Tags: excel, vba

I asked the question yesterday but the answers could not solve it...
[Selecting a range until at least one column has numeric value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660577/selecting-a-range-until-at-least-one-column-has-numeric-value)

The problem is:

I have a range of some columns and some rows which is a reference, so the formula is like this for that range (that consists of 118 rows and 7 columns):

```
{IFERROR(HLOOKUP(Data!D371:D478;Data!B361:HU367;4;FALSKT);"NA")}
```

I then copy that range (`where only 60 rows are non-blank and the rest of the rows are blank cells`) to the other range with:

```
=IF(ChosenData!B196="NA";"";ChosenData!B196)
```

and so on...

I then use the VBA to copy it over to an other sheet in my workbook:

```
Sub GetRet()
    Worksheets("ChosenData").Select
    Range("J195").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Copy

    Worksheets("Analys").Select
    Range("L10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

The sub above selects all the 118 rows `but I only want to select only the rows until the row where at least one of the columns is non-blank`.

Last post suggested to use:

```
Lastrow = Evaluate("=MATCH("""",L10:L1000&M10:M1000&N10:N1000&O1:O1000&P10:P1000&Q10:Q1000&R10:R1000,0)")
```

But that solution select some randow row (`which is non-blank`) !

Best Regards!

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: loop througnt rows: `For i=10 to 1000` and check whether all columns you need are blank. If so - rememeber `i` - it's your `lastrow` and `exit for`

Comment: @simoco I am new to Excel, come from R... Could you please post an answer, a sub? Best Regards:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("ChosenData")
        For i = 10 To 1000
            'compare concatenation of columns L:Q with empty string
            If Trim(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range("L" & i & ":Q" & i).Value)), "")) = "" Then
                lastrow = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With

    MsgBox "Lastrow is:" & lastrow
End Sub
```

if you're interesting how `Join` works in this example, look into [@Tim Williams answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395633/how-to-compare-two-entire-rows-in-a-sheet/19396257#19396257).

Futher improvment, you can change `1000` in loop to [last row of *entire sheet*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

Comment: @simoco... I run that sub but it does not return anything:/ Not MsgBox at least...

Comment: sorry, I've updated my code, try now (there should be `Exit For` instead `Exit Sub` in loop)

Comment: Yeah great! Very good answer! Trying now to get that row so I select `L10:R67` correctly:P

Comment: Something like that, but that seem wrong `Range("L10" &":" &"M & ":" & lastrow).Select`

Comment: that works `Range("L10:M" & lastrow - 1).Select` . Thanks you are the best:D